# AngularJS - automatically adding hash tag to URLs - overwriting search params

Tags: javascript, url, angularjs, angular-routing

I"m running into an issue when I click on a quicknav, the anchor tag replaces my search parameters in the URL.

`'example.com/search?hash=1234'` becomes `'example.com/search#FAQ'`

instead of `'example.com/search?hash=1234#FAQ'`

How do I fix this? Version 1.1.5

HTML anchor tags:

```
<a href="#{{page.id}}" ng-repeat="page in results.page">{{page.id}}</a>
```

I do have HTML5 mode enabled if that makes a difference:

```
.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a bit of a hacky workaround for now:

```
<a ng-href="{{resultsHash}}#{{page.id}}" ng-repeat="page in results.page">{{page.id}}</a>
```

And the value of `resultsHash`

```
$scope.resultsHash = "?hash=" + data.hash;
```

So each time they use a quickNav link, the hash will be included in the path. This isn't an ideal solution tho. But it mimics what I want done.